# HTML Regex Composition

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I am trying to capture img tag in HTML using Regex...

So these must be captured:

```
<img/>
< img id = "f" />
```

I have used:

```
"<\s*img(\s.*?)?/>"
```

But this goes wrong:

```
< img id = "/>" />
```

Any idea how to probably capture img tag??

Thanks

Comment: Which flavor of regex are you using, Perl, JavaScript, .NET...?  And do you really have tags with whitespace between opening angle bracket and the tag name?  I don't think that's legal in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a serious note: Use an xml parser instead.

```
"<\simg\sid\s=\s\"(.*?)\"\s/>"
```

Also, you should look into using a regex testing suite like [regex buddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/).

This might be a good read as well: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

```
"<\s*img\s(?:.+?\s*=\s*(\"|')?.*?\1\s*)?/>"
```

I think this should take the quotes into account. Didn't test it though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex

<\s*?img[\s\S]*?/>